# Custom animate TextView like the floating label present in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-animation

I try to achieve the same behaviour of a floating label text as the `TextInputLayout` class already does but for a different purpose

I got everything working except the x translation of the textview. I don't know how to shift the correct amount of pixels.

It moves up correctly and shrinks down correctly but does not move straigh up because the center for scale is in the middle of the text view. But I want the text view do move straigh up. So my intention was to calculate the length of the text also scale this with the scale value and divide this by 2 (left and right). This does not work. Any ideas how to achieve this no matter the text length?

```
private void triggerAnimation(boolean fadeOut) {
    if (fadeOut) {
        float xTranslation = b.tvHint.getPaint().measureText(tvHint.getHint().toString())*0.6f/2;
        tvHint.animate().translationY(-tvHint.getHeight() * 0.28f).translationXBy(-xTranslation).scaleX(0.6f).scaleY(0.6f);
    } else {
        tvHint.animate().translationY(0).translationX(0).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it turns out that it is possible to change the coordinates pivot point so this will exactly reproduce the floating label

```
private void triggerAnimation(boolean fadeOut) {
    if (fadeOut) {
        tvHint.setPivotX(0);
        tvHint.animate().translationY(-tvHint.getHeight() * 0.32f).scaleX(0.7f).scaleY(0.7f);
    } else {
        tvHint.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
    }

}
```